# SwiftUI Canvas and Gestures

Tags: swiftui

I have a canvas in which I'm drawing views. I want to be able to reposition each view on drag in the canvas, but any gesture inside an ItemView is not recognised, I was thinking of implementing gestures outside the canvas, but I couldn't find anything about canvas hit-testing to select the item I want to reposition using `context.translateBy`, I'm not completely sure how to proceed since I couldn't find much about using gestures inside the canvas with multiple views.

Current Code:

```
struct TestCanvasView: View {
    
    @FetchRequest(fetchRequest: Item.all) var items
    
    var currentItems: [Item] {
        items.filter { $0.parent == nil }
    }
    
    @State var position = CGPoint.zero
    
    var body: some View {
        Canvas { context, size in
            for currentItem in currentItems {
                let itemView = context.resolveSymbol(id: currentItem.objectID)!
               
                
                context.draw(itemView, at: currentItem.itemPosition)
               
                context.translateBy(x: position.x, y: position.y)
            

               
            }
            
        } symbols: {
            ForEach(currentItems) { item in
                ItemView(item: item)
                    .tag(item.objectID)
                 // .gesture() doesn't work here
                
            }
            
            
        }
        .gesture(DragGesture()
        .onChanged { value in
            position = value.location

        })
    }
}
```